# Binding does not work for TemplateSelector

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I have one part of the view is dynamic based on a TemplateSelector. However, the binding does not work for the controls in the DataTemplate.(The controls do show on screen, just the conetent/texts are empty). I suspect it's a DataContext issue, but couldn't figure out after a lot of searching on line. Here is my XAML:

```xml
        <Grid>
            <Grid.DataContext>
                <local:MyViewModel/>
            </Grid.DataContext>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="T1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   Text="Music"
                                   Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=textBlockStyle}" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                                 Grid.Row="0"
                                 Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=textBoxStyle}"
                                 Text="{Binding Path=MusicName}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="T2">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   Text="Currency"
                                   Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=textBlockStyle}" />
                        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"
                                  Grid.Row="0"
                                  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=comboBoxStyle}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Currency_List}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Currency}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
                <local:ProductTypeTemplateSelector T1="{StaticResource ResourceKey=T1}"
                                                   T2="{StaticResource ResourceKey=T2}"
                                                   x:Key="myTemplateSelector" />
            <Grid.Resources>
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- This biding works -->
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"  
                       Text="{Binding Path=MusicName}"/>
            <!-- This biding does not work -->
            <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                            Name="ccc"
                            Content="{Binding  Path=Product_Type}"
                            ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelector}">
            </ContentControl>
        </Grid>
```

This is my View Model (Technically, it is View Model and Model mixed together. I am not really implementing a full MVVM pattern)

```cs
    public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        SetLists();
    }



    protected void SetLists()
    {
        SetList_Product_Type();
        SetList_Currency();
    }



    protected void SearchAndPopulate()
    {
        string query = string.Format("select * from dbo.vehicle_attributes where ticker like '%{0}%'", Search_Text);
        DataView dv = DAL.ExecuteQuery(query);
        if (dv.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRowView dvr = dv[0];
            Vehicle_Id = int.Parse(dvr["vehicle_id"].ToString());
            Product_Type = dvr["product_type_name"].ToString();
            Vehicle_Name = dvr["vehicle_name"].ToString();
            Is_Onshore = dvr["domicile_name"].ToString() == "Onshore";
            Currency = dvr["currency"].ToString();
            CUSIP = dvr["CUSIP"].ToString();
            ISIN = dvr["isin"].ToString();
            Ticker = dvr["ticker"].ToString();
            Valoren = dvr["valoren"].ToString();
            PC_Class = PC_Class_List.Find(x => x.Class_Name == dvr["class_name"].ToString());
            Implementation_Type = Implementation_Type_List.Find ( x => x.Implementation_Type_Name == dvr["implementation_type_name"].ToString());
            Price_Frequency = Price_Frequency_List.Find( x => x.Price_Frequency_Name == dvr["price_freq_name"].ToString());
            Status = Status_List.Find( x => x.Status_Name == dvr["status_name"].ToString());
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dvr["last_status_update"].ToString()))
            {
                Status_Date = DateTime.Parse(dvr["last_status_update"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Status_Date = DateTime.MinValue;
            }
            switch (Product_Type)
            {
                case "Mutual Fund":
                    query = string.Format("select lf.dividend_currency, i.ticker from dbo.liquid_funds lf " + 
                                          "left join dbo.vehicles i on i.vehicle_id = lf.index_id " + 
                                          "where lf.vehicle_id ='{0}'",Vehicle_Id);
                    DataView dv_mutual_fund = DAL.ExecuteQuery(query);
                    if(dv_mutual_fund.Count > 0)
                    {
                        DataRowView dvr_mutual_fund = dv_mutual_fund[0];
                        Dividend_Currency = dvr_mutual_fund["dividend_currency"].ToString();
                        Benchmark_Ticker = dvr_mutual_fund["ticker"].ToString();


                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

    public ICommand SearchVehicleCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command.DelegateCommand(SearchAndPopulate);
        }

    }




    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }


    //ProductType
    protected List<string> _product_Type_List = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Product_Type_List
    {
        get
        {
            return _product_Type_List;
        }
        set
        {
            _product_Type_List = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Product_Type_List");
        }
    }
    protected void SetList_Product_Type()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.product_types WHERE is_enabled = 1";
        DataView dv = DAL.ExecuteQuery(query);
        List<string> l = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dv.Count; i++)
        {
            l.Add(dv[i]["product_type_name"].ToString());
        }
        Product_Type_List = l;

    }

    protected string _product_type;
    public string Product_Type
    {
        get
        {
            return _product_type;
        }
        set
        {
            _product_type = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Product_Type");
            SetList_Implementation_Type();
        }
    }


    //Currency
    protected List<string> _currency_List = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Currency_List
    {
        get
        {
            return _currency_List;
        }
        set
        {
            _currency_List = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Currency_List");
        }
    }
    protected void SetList_Currency()
    {
        string query = "SELECT currency FROM dbo.currencies";
        DataView dv = DAL.ExecuteQuery(query);
        List<string> l = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dv.Count; i++)
        {
            l.Add(dv[i]["currency"].ToString());
        }
        Currency_List = l;

    }

    protected string _currency;
    public string Currency
    {
        get
        {
            return _currency;
        }
        set
        {
            _currency = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Currency");
        }
    }



    // Music Name
    protected string _musicName;
    public string MusicName
    {
        get
        {
            return _musicName;
        }
        set
        {
            _musicName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MusicName");
        }
    }

    }
```

This is the class interface (sorry for the formatting above, but somehow I can't get it right):

And this is my DelegateCommand class:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _action;

    public DelegateCommand(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
         _action();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the DataTemplateSelector:

```cs
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate T1 { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate T2 { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item,
  DependencyObject container)
    {
        string product_type = (string)item;
        if (product_type == "Type1")
            return T1;
        else
        return T2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't set a `Content="{Binding YourContent}"` in the content control so it doesn't know what to put into the templates.

Comment: Sorry, there was a Content="{Binding  Path=Product_Type}" there, I don't know why I took it out. Now I added it back, it still does not work. The ContentTemplateSelector works fine, because as the Content change, the UI changes. However, the TextBox and Combobox inside the DataTemplates do not have any value bind to its Text/ItemSource.

Comment: The DataContext for your templates will be the instance of 'Product_Type', are `MusicName`, `Currency_List` and `Currency` properties of `Product_Type`?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your ViewModel?

Comment: added. But somehow I cannot get the format right

Comment: Currency_List and Currency are properties of "MyViewModel", Product_Type is also a property on MyViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataContext of a DataTemplate is set to the object that it is bound to. So in your case the DataContext for your Templates are `Product_Type` and you are expecting it to be `MyViewModel`.

There is a workaround for what you need. It uses a [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) binding and [`FindAncester`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesourcemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to access the DataContext of the Parent object.

Your DataTemplate bindings should look like this:

**XAML**

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="T1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Text="Music"
                               Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=textBlockStyle}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                             Grid.Row="0"
                             Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=textBoxStyle}"
                             Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}, Path=DataContext.MusicName}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="T2">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Text="Currency"
                               Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=textBlockStyle}" />
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=comboBoxStyle}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}, Path=DataContext.Currency_List}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}, Path=DataContext.Currency}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

**From MSDN**

> *Find Ancestor* - Refers to the ancestor in the parent chain of the data-bound element. You can use this to bind to an ancestor of a specific type or its subclasses.

The `AncestorType` attribute goes up the visual tree and finds the first Ancestor of the given type, in this case it's looking for `ContentControl` the path to the required property can then be set relative to this.

**Update**

Think of a template as a guide on how to display an object. The DataContext of the DataTemplate is going to be whatever object it is asked it to display.

In this case the ContentControl is told to display `Product_Type` and, depending on the value of `Product_Type`, to use a particular Template. `Product_Type` is given to the DataTemplate and becomes the DataContext.

[WPFTutorials](http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html) has some good examples.

Comment: Thanks, nmaait! However, could you help me understand, why is the DataContext on my DataTemplate Product_Type? I thought Content on ContentControl was just fed into the "item" parameter of the SelectTemplate method on the ContentTemplateSelector. If I am wrong, then what should be fed into SelectTemplate?

Comment: Btw, I just edited my question to add my DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: Thanks! Very clear, will try it out, and I believe this solves my problem. Accepting your answer and +1.